# Can't access port 80 for web service on Azure machine

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine with NSG and I allowed inbound traffic for 80 port. But I can't access to 80 port.

A public IP is 54.44.23.x and private IP is 10.0.0.x. It's working with private IP address on VM itself.

Comment: In Azure, NSG can associate to VM and Vnet sunbet, please check the NSG settings.

Comment: Have you also allowed port 80 in the OS firewall in the VM? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your virtual network **subnet NSG settings**, make sure port 80 have allowed in NSG inbound rules.

[image]

By the way, you should check **VM's firewall**, make sure port 80 allowed in that inbound rules.