# Assign public IP to VM on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, windows-server-2016

I have created a VM instance on Windows Azure is a Windows Server 2016 and I have deployed a web application on the server. When I run the web application with localhost or private IP and it's all working fine. But, when I try typing the address with the public IP address that provided by the Azure VM instance, and the page just didn't show up.

I thought the default assigned public IP should have already mapped it to the private IP address?

Please advice.
Thank you.

Updated the NSG setting with the advice. Still no luck!
[image]

Comment: Please check your firewall settings and NSG settings:)

Comment: Can you ping the IP address? Also, did you try using a DNS name for this instance, that is pretty much neat and simple to handle in most cases.

Comment: I couldn't reach the public IP from my local machine. Can't ping.

Comment: Is there a step that I had missed when I was creating the VM instance?

Answer (score 1):

Have you allow port in **NSG inbound firewal**l settings and **OS's firewall** inbound rules.

Please follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) to add port to NSG inbound rules via Azure portal.

Also you should add ports to OS firewall inbound rules.

Note:

NSG can associate to Vnet and Subnet, please check them.

Here a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528624/cant-access-port-80-for-web-service-on-azure-machine/49528706#49528706) about it.

Comment: Have you check your subnet NSG settings and OS firewall settings?

Answer (score 0):

Azure blocks all ports by default, you need to open port 80 (443 if you are using SSL) and map them to port 80 on the server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

I think the config is on VMs > Networks > Inbound Rules

Comment: I simple deployed and run the application listening to port 80, so it should work without any firewall configuration as you mentioned the default port is 80.

Comment: No... All azure VMs have firewall enabled by default, so you should add your endpoints on the azure control panel https://youtu.be/vRwUWD3WvTk?t=6m8s

Comment: I have updated the NSG settings as per advice. Still no luck! Please see the screenshot above. Thanks